# How to use callbacks in if statements?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, callback

Hello I have the problem that I cant understand how to write the callbacks in the if statements further. I want that the first if statement is executed then the actionArray function. After the actionArray function is 100 % done, he should check the second if statement. And also his function. How can I reallize it ? I think I have a blocked thought.

```
function addFunction(fn){
 if(rowChanged && upOk){
     jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);            
     formmodified = false;              
     actionArray(updateArray, "update", fn);    
 }
 if(rowChanged && saveOk){
    jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);
    formmodified = false;
    actionArray(saveArray, "save", fn); 
 }
 fn();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry too much, callback logic is really "reverse" and it's not trivial to understand it at first.

```
function addFunction(fn){
    if(rowChanged && saveOk){
        // We will need this second step...
        var org_fn = fn;
        fn = function() {
                 jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);
                 formmodified = false;
                 actionArray(saveArray, "save", org_fn);
             };
    }
    if(rowChanged && upOk){
        // We need the first step
        var org_fn_2 = fn;
        fn = function() {
                 jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);            
                 formmodified = false;              
                 actionArray(updateArray, "update", org_fn_2);
             };
    }
    setTimeout(fn, 0); // Schedule the call
}
```

The idea is: the caller gives you a function to be called when everything is completed. It's expected that your function returns immediately, not that will call the callback immediately. So in case of an empty processing it should be

```
function addFunction(fn){
    setTimeout(fn, 0);
}
```

so we return immediately and the completion callback will be called as soon as possible.

If there is an asynchronous processing to do then we instead replace the passed callback with another one that will ask to do the processing and, on completion, will call the original callback. This is where Javascript scoping rules are a bit annoying and we're forced to declare a different variable `org_fn` to store the original callback and wrap the passed one in the function that will do the processing.

In case there are potentially TWO steps then we need to do this wrapping again, using a different `org_fn_2` variable.

The wrapping needs also to be done in reverse order, because we want the second step to be done after completion of first (in case first step is present).

Comment: Ufff very hard to understand for me, but I think I get it... First I have to "play" a little bit with it to understand it better. Ill come back if I have some more questions. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

*Edit, looks like i missed a detail in the question...*

So, what you want to do is perform operations in series, asynchronously.

Here's something reusable:

```
series([
    function(callback) {
        if ( rowChanged && upOk ) {
            jQuery('#save_btn').prop('disabled', true);
            formmodified = false;
            actionArray(updateArray, 'update', callback);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    },
    function(callback) {
        if ( rowChanged && saveOk ){
            jQuery('#save_btn').prop('disabled', true);
            formmodified = false;
            actionArray(saveArray, 'save', callback); 
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }
],fn);

function series(taskList,done) {
    var next = taskList.shift();
    if ( typeof next === 'function' ) {
        next(series.bind(this,taskList,done));
    } else if ( typeof done === 'function' ) {
        done();
    }
}
```

...and this is a mock version, all spelled out (with timeouts to represent async tasks):

```
// first create the task list
var tasks = [
    function one(callback) { // this is a "medium" difficulty task
        console.log('one',new Date()); // so you can see some output
        setTimeout(callback,1000); // return callback after 1 second (async)
    },
    function two(callback) { // this is a "hard" difficulty task
        console.log('two',new Date()); // more output
        if ( true ) { // after some initial logic
            setTimeout(function() { // and then an async task for 500ms
                if ( true ) { // and more logic later
                    callback(); // issue the callback
                }
            },500);
        }
    },
    function three(callback) { // this is an easy task
        console.log('three',new Date());
        callback(); // return callback right away
    }
];

// `series` will handle moving the task list along
function series(taskList,done) {
    var next = taskList.shift(); // get the next function to call
    if ( typeof next === 'function' ) { // if there is one, and it is a function
        next(series.bind(this,taskList,done)); // execute it, and pass it the callback for the next task
    } else if ( typeof done === 'function' ) { // if there isn't another task, but there's a done function
        done(); // call the complete function, this is guaranteed to fire, if defined
    }
}
series(
    tasks.slice(0), // make a copy of tasks to save for later (if you want)
    function complete() { // complete will be called when the tasks have run out
        console.log('complete!',new Date());
    }
); 
//series(tasks); // alternatively, w/o the copy `.slice(0)` tasks will be depleted when it is done
```

---

OLD:

Just keep nesting lambdas:

```
function addFunction(fn) {
    if (rowChanged && upOk) {
        jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);
        formmodified = false;
        actionArray(updateArray, "update", function() {
            if (rowChanged && saveOk) {
                jQuery("#save_btn").prop('disabled', true);
                formmodified = false;
                actionArray(saveArray, "save", fn);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Pretty ugly, but typical, until you start really organizing your code and/or using libs (e.g. [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)).

Comment: This won't call the completion callback if there's nothing to do. Also the second test in the original code is independent on if the first test is satisfied (they're two sequential `IF`s, not two nested ones).

Comment: I thought about this too. But this wouldnt work if just the "saveOk" is true.

Comment: @user2889693 updated the answer so there isn't any dependent/nested logic, totally overlooked that detail!